# How to handle two possible position of a group in regular expression in ruby?

Tags: regex, ruby

I have a regular expression like this `(HN)(#{VAL})(#{dens})(#{temp})(C|A)#?{temp})#?(A|0)`

"temp" can either be at 4th position or at 7th position in my regular expression . How to handle this pattern in ruby regex ?

Example of the input data:

```
HN58 C 256 A T "I" 85E or HN58 C 257 A T 85 "I" E
```

Comment: Please, can you add example of input data?

Comment: HN58 C 256 A T "I" 85E or HN58 C 257 A T 85 "I" E  as you can see in this expression there are two possible position of "I". it can either be before "85" or after "85".

Comment: Thank you, but none of your examples doesn't fit your regex. Please, can you fix it? Basically I would probably use two regexp or nested matching groups.

Comment: (/\A(HN58)(C|V)(256|257)(A|R)(T|P)(I|SR)(85|10)(E)\z/) or (/\A(HN58)(C|V)(256|257)(A|R)(T|P)(85|10)(I|SR)(E)\z/)  these are the two possible regular expression for the above input . how to handle both of the above inputs in single regular expression ?

Comment: When @Iojza asked you to add an example, he/she meant for you to do so by editing your question.

Comment: If your regular expression were `/a(#{b})c(#{d})(e)f/` and `(#{g})` were to be inserted before `c` or after `(#{d})` you would use "or" (`|`) within a non-capture group: `/a(#{b})(?:(#{g})c(#{d})|c(#{d})(#{g}))(e)f/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still not sure what's your data. But with the help of https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/doc/regexp_rdoc.html#label-Capturing try:

```
regex = /HN(?<val>\d+) (C|V) (?<dens>\d+) (A|R) (T|P) (((?<temp>\d+) (85|10))|((85|10) (?<temp>\d+))) (E)/

regex =~ "HN58 C 256 A T 37 85 E"
puts val,dens,temp

regex =~ "HN58 C 257 A T 85 36 E"
puts val,dens,temp
```

https://rubular.com/r/vD98oRgaDGLb8W

Answer (score 0):

[This RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/7Idi7D/1/) might help you to design a proper matching for your input strings:

```
HN[0-9]{2}\s[A-Z]\s[0-9]{3}\s[A-Z\s0-9]+\x22I\x22\s[A-Z0-9]+
```

[image]